# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 with respect to _VideoPlayer

Tags: ios, xcode

Not sure what is going on. I built my project perfectly in Unity for iOS, but once I try to run it on Xcode, I always get the following error:

I have searched google and gone through every possible fix on stackoverflow but did not fix it so I am unsure if this is very specific to my code:

- Disabled bitcode
- Rebuilt the project using strictly 1 scene in Unity and still get the same error.
- Removed search header in build settings

I genuinely out of ideas of what is wrong.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_VideoPlayerPluginRewindVideo", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginRewindVideo_m3082508113 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginRewindVideo_m3082508113)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginCurFrameTexture", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginCurFrameTexture_m1593954222 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_get_videoTexture_m2577019922 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginCurFrameTexture_m1593954222)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginDurationSeconds", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginDurationSeconds_m2690910420 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_get_duration_m277410481 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginDurationSeconds_m2690910420)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginPlayerReady", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginPlayerReady_m519815871 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_get_ready_m1468627929 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginPlayerReady_m519815871)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginSetSpeed", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_SetSpeed_m1821975912 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetSpeed_m2537395036 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetSpeed_m2537395036)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginSetVolume", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_SetVolume_m1145568362 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetVolume_m1552845941 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetVolume_m1552845941)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginResumeVideo", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_RePlay_m309591828 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginResumeVideo_m2823521169 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginResumeVideo_m2823521169)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginExtents", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginExtents_m3404099935 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_get_videoSize_m23492929 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginExtents_m3404099935)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginPauseVideo", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_Pause_m3579890352 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginPauseVideo_m1054515433 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginPauseVideo_m1054515433)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginSetTexture", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetTexture_m1295528375 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_SetUnityTexture_m2241657163 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetTexture_m1295528375)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginStopVideo", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_UnLoad_m2955987449 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginStopVideo_m2700854715 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_Stop_m1894964176 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginStopVideo_m2700854715)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginSeekToVideo", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_Play_m4289596389 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_SetSeekPosition_m3285971868 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSeekToVideo_m687589631 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSeekToVideo_m687589631)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginIsPlaying", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginIsPlaying_m2767458669 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_get_isPlaying_m166503759 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginIsPlaying_m2767458669)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginError", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_GetStatus_m1340805735 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginError_m264942449 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginError_m264942449)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginPlayVideo", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_Play_m4289596389 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginPlayVideo_m3732859185 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginPlayVideo_m3732859185)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginFinish", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_GetStatus_m1340805735 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginFinish_m2746721115 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginFinish_m2746721115)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginCurTimeSeconds", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_GetSeekPosition_m2015813757 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginCurTimeSeconds_m495840142 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_get_currentTime_m3530085166 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginCurTimeSeconds_m495840142)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginDestroyInstance", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_UnLoad_m2955987449 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_Destroy_m2904930778 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginDestroyInstance_m1744225672 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginDestroyInstance_m1744225672)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginCanOutputToTexture", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_Load_m4029719587 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginCanOutputToTexture_m32469285 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginCanOutputToTexture_m32469285)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginSetLoop", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_SetLooping_m4176452013 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetLoop_m2591582794 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetLoop_m2591582794)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginLoadVideo", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_Load_m4029719587 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginLoadVideo_m3560986880 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginLoadVideo_m3560986880)
  "_VideoPlayerPluginCreateInstance", referenced from:
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_Call_SetUnityActivity_m1877101062 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginCreateInstance_m3075383955 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginCreateInstance_m3075383955)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed!!! Reimport your media player plugin and build again. In my case that was EasyMovieTexture!